# LAMP display php errors

Tags: php, apache, debugging, lamp

I've installed developer's LAMP server and made changes on php.ini

**display_errors On**

**display_startup_errors On**

but it doesn't display any errors or even a little warning, what's the problem, what's wrong?

Comment: did you restart the appache after your changes in the php.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that most systems have two php.ini files, one for the webserver and one for the command line. Do a `phpinfo()` to see which one you need to edit.

Comment: So you're saying you edited both to `display_errors=On` and `error_reporting=E_ALL`, restarted the httpd and still no errors get displayed?

Answer (score 3):

Did you restart apache?

Comment: For sure I restarted web server it doesn't affect anyway

Answer (score 0):

Also set **error_reporting** to E_ALL

Answer (score 0):

change the following variables in your php.ini

```
; display_errors
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT 
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

; html_errors 
; Default Value: On 
; Development Value: On 
; Production value: Off

; log_errors
; Default Value: On 
; Development Value: On 
; Production Value: On
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

1. I changed from `display_errors=Off` to `display_errors=On` in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` file
2. and restarted lampp `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp/restart`