# Zend server CE - Will not load .php file rather downloads it

Tags: zend-server

I installed Zend Server CE on Windows 8.  When I try to load a .php file in my browser it does not load but downloads the php file instead.

My root for the server is C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\

I looked everywhere on the web but there is no documentation.

Comment: I would recommend against having your document root in program files because of all the security. Reinstall it outside of program files and it might/will probably work.

Comment: so I installed at the root of C drive, c:\Zend, but still just downloads file.

Comment: How do you invoke the file? You cannot use the full windows path there ie: c:\Zend\apache2\etc.. But probably localhost/yourfile.php or 127.0.0.1/yourfile.php. Can you open zend's interface at localhost:100081?

Comment: so I tried http://localhost:81/hello.php and I got this error message:                    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: also I can access the server page by using http://localhost:81/

Comment: Well then it serves .php files. Now enable errors in php.ini and find out what is wrong probably some path. You are getting a php error and they are set to not display so you get the server error. That does mean php files are parsed.

Comment: I posted this as a answer since in my opinion it helped. Feel free to disagree or agree.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against having your document root in program files because of all the security. Reinstall it outside of program files and it might/will probably work.

How do you invoke the file? You cannot use the full windows path there ie: c:\Zend\apache2\etc.. But probably localhost/yourfile.php or 127.0.0.1/yourfile.php. Can you open zend's interface at localhost:100081?

If you get a internal server error well then it serves php files. Now enable errors in php.ini and find out what is wrong probably some path. You are getting a php error and they are set to not display so you get the server error. That does mean php files are parsed by apache and not downloaded. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905860/lamp-display-php-errors) here on so has pretty much what you need to configure.

Just remembered you had the zend-framework tag so you could check in application.ini for error handling settings.